# Elfinder Arabic Issue

Tags: php, jquery, html, elfinder

I have an issue with the Arabic language on `Elfinder`. When I create a new folder and named it in Arabic, it shows good on `elfinder` like below:

[image: elfinder v2.1.7]

But on the locale system, the name is totally different with some special characters like this: `Ø§Ø¨Ù„Ø§Ø¨Ù„Ø§`

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Mohammad, in what server (OS, Version) you are working with?

Comment: Am using wamp server: php 5.6 and Windows 7 64 bits

Answer (score 0):

Mohammad:

Have you checked the Connector configuration options?

There is a value for "locale" configuration, where you can set the right characters set for your Elfinder application:

I believe "ar_SA.UTF-8" is the locale value for Arabic encoding in Linux, and "Arabic_Saudi Arabia.1256" is the locale value for Arabic encoding in Windows...

```
<?php

$opts = array(
    'locale' => 'Arabic_Saudi Arabia.1256', // or 'locale' => 'ar_SA.UTF-8',
    'roots'  => array(
        array(
            'driver' => 'LocalFileSystem',
            'path'   => '/path/to/files/',
            'URL'    => 'http://localhost/to/files/'
        )
    )
);

// run elFinder
$connector = new elFinderConnector(new elFinder($opts));
$connector->run();
```

Hope this helps!

**Reference**: https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Connector-configuration-options